Prove or disprove an integral identity
We define $$\mathbb{C}^{+n}:=\{ (z_1,\cdots,z_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n\colon\text{Im}[z_j]> 0 \text{ for } 1\leq j\leq n \}.$$ Let $h$ be a rational function (quotient of two polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[z_1,\cdots,z_n]$) such that $h(\mathbb{C}^{+n})\subset \mathbb{C}^{+1}\cup \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $h$ has no poles on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to prove or disprove the following identity
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\ell=3}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_{\ell}-z_{\ell}}-\frac{1}{t_{\ell}-\overline{z_{\ell}}}\right) \text{Im}[h(t_1,\cdots,t_n)]dt_1dt_2\cdots dt_n=0
\end{align}
for all $z=(z_1,\cdots,z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^{+n}.$

I have not come up with any counterexample. A direct approach seems difficult since I do not have a simple form for how $h$, and more importantly its denominator, should look.
Edit 1:
I will include some context.
The question is related to an article I am reading on Herglotz-Nevanlinna function, analytic functions that map $\mathbb{C}^{+n}$ into the upper half-plane, like the function $h$ above, but they do not need to be rational. The article can be found here. It turns out such functions have an integral representation with respect to a positive Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies some growth condition and another condition. I am interested in Corollary 4.6 in the paper which claims that if the function can be continuously extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$ then its corresponding measure in the integral representation should be
$$\mu(U)=\int_{U}\text{Im}[h(\vec{t})]d\vec{t}$$
for a bounded Borel set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. That this measure satisfies the growth condition is immediate. The second condition amounts to showing the above identity.
Edit 2: Here is a solution attempt.
We have
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\text{Im}[h(\vec{t})]dt_1\cdots dt_n=\\
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\text{Im}[h(\vec{t}+\mathbf{i}\epsilon)]dt_1\cdots dt_n.
\end{align}
Where $\mathbf{i}\in \mathbb{C}^n$ is the vector with entries $i.$ We have by Corollary 4.6, (ii)
\begin{align}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\text{Im}[h(\vec{t}+\mathbf{i}\epsilon)]dt_1\cdots dt_n=\\
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{\pi^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathcal{P}(\vec{t}+\mathbf{i}\epsilon,\vec{x})d\mu(\vec{x})\right)dt_1\cdots dt_n
\end{align}
where $\mu$ is the measure corresponding to the function $h$ in Theorem 4.1.
Lebesgue’s dominated convergence theorem allows us to change the order of the limit and the ﬁrst integral. We thus arrive at the expression
\begin{align}
    \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\pi^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mathcal{P}(\vec{t}+\mathbf{i}\epsilon,\vec{x})d\mu(\vec{x})\right)dt_1\cdots dt_n=\\
    \frac{1}{\pi^n}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\ \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\mathcal{P}(\vec{t}+\mathbf{i}\epsilon,\vec{x})d\mu(\vec{x})dt_1\cdots dt_n
\end{align}
Applying
Fubini’s theorem allows us to change the order of integration and we arrive at the expression
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{\pi^n}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\ \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\mathcal{P}(\vec{t}+\mathbf{i}\epsilon,\vec{x})dt_1\cdots dt_nd\mu(\vec{x}).
\end{align}
We note that
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{P}(\vec{t}+\mathbf{i}\epsilon,\vec{x})=\prod_{\ell=l}^n\frac{\text{Im}[(\vec{t}+\mathbf{i}\epsilon)_\ell]}{|x_\ell-(\vec{t}+\mathbf{i}\epsilon)_\ell|^2}=\prod_{\ell=l}^n\frac{\epsilon}{|x_\ell-t_\ell-i\epsilon|^2}=\prod_{\ell=l}^n\frac{\epsilon}{(x_\ell-t_\ell)^2+\epsilon^2}.
\end{align}
We thus have
\begin{align}
      \frac{1}{\pi^n}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\ \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\prod_{\ell=l}^n\frac{\epsilon}{(x_\ell-t_\ell)^2+\epsilon^2}dt_1\cdots dt_nd\mu(\vec{x}).
\end{align}
We will calculate the integral
\begin{align}
   \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\ \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\prod_{\ell=l}^n\frac{\epsilon}{(x_\ell-t_\ell)^2+\epsilon^2}dt_1\cdots dt_n
\end{align}
By Residue calculus we have
\begin{align}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{(t_1-z_1)^2}\frac{\epsilon}{(x_1-t_1)^2+\epsilon^2}dt_1=2\pi i\left(\frac{-i}{2}\frac{1}{(z_1-x_2-i\epsilon)^2}\right)=\pi\frac{1}{(z_1-x_1-i\epsilon)^2}\\
    \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{(t_2-\overline{z_2})^2}\frac{\epsilon}{(x_2-t_2)^2+\epsilon^2}dt_1=2\pi i\left(\frac{-i}{2}\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2-i\epsilon)^2}\right)=\pi\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2-i\epsilon)^2}.
\end{align}
We therefore get
\begin{align}
       \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\ \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\prod_{\ell=l}^n\frac{\epsilon}{(x_\ell-t_\ell)^2+\epsilon^2}dt_1\cdots dt_n=\\
       \pi^2\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2-i\epsilon)^2} \frac{1}{(z_1-x_1-i\epsilon)^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-2}} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\prod_{\ell=3}^n\frac{\epsilon}{(x_\ell-t_\ell)^2+\epsilon^2}dt_3\cdots dt_n.
\end{align}
By Residue calculus (tedious, but straightforward) we again find
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\overline{z_j}}\right)\frac{\epsilon}{(x_j-t_j)^2+\epsilon^2}dt_j=\\
2\pi i \left[\frac{\epsilon}{(x_j-z_j)^2+\epsilon^2}-\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-z_j}-\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-\overline{z_j}}\right)\right].
\end{align}
In total we get
\begin{align}
       \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\ \frac{1}{\left(t_{1}-z_{1}\right)^2\left(t_{2}-\overline{z_{2}}\right)^2} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\prod_{\ell=l}^n\frac{\epsilon}{(x_\ell-t_\ell)^2+\epsilon^2}dt_1\cdots dt_n=\\
       \pi^2\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2-i\epsilon)^2} \frac{1}{(z_1-x_1-i\epsilon)^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-2}} \prod_{\substack{j=3}}^n\left(\frac{1}{t_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{t_j-\bar{z}_j}\right)\prod_{\ell=3}^n\frac{\epsilon}{(x_\ell-t_\ell)^2+\epsilon^2}dt_3\cdots dt_n=\\
       \pi^2(2\pi i)^{n-2}\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2-i\epsilon)^2} \frac{1}{(z_1-x_1-i\epsilon)^2}\prod_{j=3}^n\left[\frac{\epsilon}{(x_j-z_j)^2+\epsilon^2}-\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-z_j}-\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-\overline{z_j}}\right)\right].
\end{align}
The original integral then becomes
\begin{align}
     \frac{1}{\pi^n}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\pi^2(2\pi i)^{n-2}\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2-i\epsilon)^2} \frac{1}{(z_1-x_1-i\epsilon)^2}\cdot \\
     \notag \prod_{j=3}^n\left[\frac{\epsilon}{(x_j-z_j)^2+\epsilon^2}-\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-z_j}-\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-\overline{z_j}}\right)\right]d\mu(\vec{x}).
\end{align}
Since the integrand in the above equation is continuous as a function of $\epsilon$, we again use Lebesgue’s dominated convergence theorem to change the order of the limit and the integral
\begin{align}
     \frac{1}{\pi^n}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\pi^2(2\pi i)^{n-2}\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2-i\epsilon)^2} \frac{1}{(z_1-x_1-i\epsilon)^2}\cdot \\
     \notag \prod_{j=3}^n\left[\frac{\epsilon}{(x_j-z_j)^2+\epsilon^2}-\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-z_j}-\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-\overline{z_j}}\right)\right]d\mu(\vec{x})=\\
     \frac{1}{\pi^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\pi^2(2\pi i)^{n-2}\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2-i\epsilon)^2} \frac{1}{(z_1-x_1-i\epsilon)^2}\cdot \\
     \notag \prod_{j=3}^n\left[\frac{\epsilon}{(x_j-z_j)^2+\epsilon^2}-\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-z_j}-\frac{1}{x_j+i\epsilon-\overline{z_j}}\right)\right]d\mu(\vec{x})=\\
     \frac{1}{\pi^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\pi^2(2\pi i)^{n-2}\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2)^2} \frac{1}{(z_1-x_1)^2}\cdot
      \prod_{j=3}^n-\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{x_j-\overline{z_j}}\right)d\mu(\vec{x})=\\
      \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2)^2} \frac{1}{(z_1-x_1)^2}\cdot
      \prod_{j=3}^n\left(\frac{1}{x_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{x_j-\overline{z_j}}\right)d\mu(\vec{x})
\end{align}
but since $\mu$ is a Nevanlinna measure, it satisfies the Nevanlinna condition (Theorem 5.1 (d)) which is equivalent to
\begin{align}
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{(z_1-x_1)^2} \frac{1}{(\overline{z_2}-x_2)^2} \cdot
      \prod_{j=3}^n\left(\frac{1}{x_j-z_j}-\frac{1}{x_j-\overline{z_j}}\right)d\mu(\vec{x})=0
\end{align}
for all $\vec{z}=(z_,\cdots,z_n)\in \mathbb{C}^{+n}$, which finishes the proof.

Can you give some context for this problem? Or is this just a random homework question?

I have added some context now. I will shortly add my attempt at a proof.

Added my attempted proof and checked it again, any comments are appreciated.

I looked it trough a few times, it looks fine to me.
